# How to exclude a dependency coming from spring boot in gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, log4j

MY project has spring boot 2.3.0.RELEASE dependency and as a result we have certain log4j dependencies like  org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.2 coming in our dependency through it.

I want to exclude this from our dependency tree.
The problem is we have added spring dependency in ext block

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.3.0.RELEASE'
    sonarqubeVersion = '2.7.1'
    gradleOSpackage = '1.9.4'
    jfrogVersion = '2.2.4'
    asciidoctorVersion = '1.5.8.1'
  }
```

When i have a dependency in implementation block I exclude the unwanted dependency like

```
implementation ('io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry:5.3.0') {
        exclude(group='org.slf4j',module='slf4j-loh4j12')
    }
```

But in this case ,I don't know how to exclude the coming log4j dependencies from spring boot.

Comment: By default spring boot uses logback, so you explicitly configured it to use log4j2. How to specify a specific version for log4j2 (or any other managed dependency) is explained in the documentation.

Comment: We are using log-back only but when i see the dependency tree - i see that there is log4j-api dependency as well which is coming from spring-boot starter-web module

Comment: Which isn't a problem see https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot (the issue is with log4j2 implementation **not** the api).

Comment: I will change my question to reflect this fact and maybe others will find it helpful too

Answer (score 4):

If it's a transitive dependency and we are sure that we want to exclude it totally, one can use configurations.all block in build.gradle file like this:

```
configurations.all {
  exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-api'
}
```